# Including the Google Maps API multiple times warning on javascript/mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I've been getting the warning message

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

Each time I open a different tab of my website, as each tab has its own map to show to the users.

The way I've made the code to call the google API was this:

```
function loadMapScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

And I call it here:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     loadMapScript();
     ... ... ...
```

The website has various tabs and when each one of them opens, the script is called, hence why it's there multiple times, I got that far.

What I didn't get is how I stop this from happening, I've tried to perform a few verification's inside the `loadMapScript` function but they did not work at all. I'd like to know if someone knows a way to make this verification inside the `loadMapScript` function, to prevent it from adding the google API script more than once.

Comment: Why you are not use one master page for this and load script once on it?

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it required me to do the following verification, it was simpler than I thought:

```
var children = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].src == script.src) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (found == false) { document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); }
```

Thanks for the attempt to help at least

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same type of problem. This occurs if your web page including maps api more than one time.

I have checked in my case there was a .js file that was also calling maps api, so please first check if you are including maps api more than one time, if you are, remove the one.

Comment: I know that the web page does have the maps api referenced more than once since each time I open a new tab, I call that function to add it. What I'm looking for is if there is any way to perform a verification inside the function that allows me to check if it's already there.